# SpriteKit Physicsbody and timing of .allContactedBodies()

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a spritekit scene with various objects on it. I want to be able to remove these objects in a wide circle around a user's touch event. In my touchesBegan function I have the following code which creates a physicsbody and checks if it contacts any objects:

```
var bigNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
bigNode.position = touchLocation!
var bigCircle = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 100, center: touchLocation!)
bigNode.physicsBody = bigCircle
bigNode.strokeColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
bigNode.zPosition = CGFloat.max
bigNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
bigNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Beam.rawValue
bigNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Target.rawValue
bigNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Target.rawValue
bigNode.name = "temp"
gameLayer.addChild(bigNode)
if let targets = bigNode.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies(){
   for target in targets{
       removeTarget(target as? SKPhysicsBody, location: target.position)
    }
 }
```

I only draw the circle so I can explicitly see what should be contacted in the simulator. The call `bigNode.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()` always returns an empty array, even when I can see clearly that there are objects in the circle.

Does spritekit need a tick of `update` or something like that in order for that array to be populated? What am I doing wrong here?

For more info, here's the Bitmasks for the targets

```
target.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Target.rawValue
target.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Target.rawValue | ColliderType.Wall.rawValue | ColliderType.Beam.rawValue
target.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue | ColliderType.Target.rawValue | ColliderType.Beam.rawValue
```

And here's my collider enum:

```
enum ColliderType: UInt32 {
    case Target = 1
    case Beam = 2
    case Wall = 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, when you touch somewhere : you create an area (bigNode), from which each node (target) inside will be removed.

The `allContactedBodies` will return *an array of SKPhysicsBody objects that this body is in contact with*. However, this as to run in the `update` method apparently. Which is very costly in processing time.

That said, you might want to try it. But you could also try to stick with the `didBeginContact` method.